# I need to convert a binary string to ascii array using javascript. (UTF-16 to ascii conversion)

Tags: javascript, binary, utf-16

I want to read "binary" data from a text file in to a javascript string(which i did) and convert the bytes to an array of ascii values. I have been trying to accomplish this for a few days and could not find a solution as i have not enough experience with utf-16 or js.

The data i am trying to convert is not text. Most of the examples on the site deals with strings like "Hello" or so which i could not get to work. The binary data consists of some (220032 to be precise) bytes which are values between 0 and 255.

I would be grateful if someone could point me to the right direction.

example :
the original file consists of (the byte array i want to get):
hex: 80 00 F5 03 7E 36 41 01     (decimal : 128 0 245 3 126 54 65 1)

for these bytes i get (using charCodeAt):
decimal : 65533 0 65533 3 121 94 20 1

---

Some more information about the question as stackoverflow stated that it is not clear enough.

I have a thermal camera that has a resolution of 382x288 which means 110016 pixels. Every pixel is represented with an unsigned short which is 2 bytes long per pixel. makingone frame of thermal data 220032 bytes. I have limited space so i am not considering json, xml etc. So i got the data from the camera using a c++ program that i wrote and wrote it to a text file as ascii characters.

The customer wanted to see the image on a local server all through his company (TV's Computers Tablets etc). So i decided to take the asp/javascript way for this project. I am not very good with javascript so did not know until much later that javascript used UTF-16 for strings which i did not want as i needed the ascii codes of each character in the file.

Thanks to 'Joachim Sauer' as he pointed me to the right direction i was able to solve the issue without much hassle using fetch and Uint8Array.

```
async load_Frame(p_filename){
    await fetch("./frames/"+p_filename+".txt")
    .then(response=>{
        if (!response.ok) throw new Error("problem");
        return response.arrayBuffer();
    }).then(data=>{
         //Here i have the frame as i wanted.
         let frame = new Uint8Array(data);
    }
    }).catch(function(e){
          console.log(e);
    })
    }
```

and the final product. :)
I did not include the thermal conversion routines as they were out of the scope of the question.

[image]

Comment: yes, just realized that before hitting refresh. Is there a way to correct it, i wonder?

Comment: There's an "edit" link under the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't interpret arbitrary binary data as UTF-8 and expect it to work (i.e. be able to round-trip).

UTF-8 has a certain amount of error-detection built in, which means there's plenty of byte sequences that are not valid UTF-8.

Those will reports in errors.

*Usually* those errors will be silently signaled by producing [a Unicode Replacement Character U+FFFD](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm), but they could also be reported via an exception or error code of some kind.

U+FFFD also *happens to be* the Unicode codepoint 65533, so that's exactly what's happening here.

One or more bytes that are not a valid UTF-8 sequence are "decoded" into this replacement character. Note that the erroneous bytes are no longer visible in the resulting string: all erroneous sequences are collapsed to that one character. There are specific rules how multiple subsequent errors are to be handled, but fundamentally you just lose that information.

I can't really tell you how to "fix" this, because fundamentally trying to interpret non-text binary data as UTF-8 will just not work.

If you explained *why* you want to do this, we could maybe suggest alternative solutions. This is probably an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Its clear about the FFFD now. UTF-8 is wrong as T.J. Crowder pointed out. I just want to get the ascii values of each byte of the text. I should update the question accordingly.

Comment: @Karter: ASCII isn't defined above 127, so any byte with the highest-value bit set will be similarly borked. Why are you trying to interpret non-text data as text anyway, this by itself is a fundamentally broken thing to try to do and I'm reluctant to provide a way that "works" without knowing if it's truly necessary.

Comment: This is some data from a Thermal camera. On the c++ side i got the data as an array of unsigned shorts. I have little space on the server (36TB) which will hold the data, so i had to have the smallest file. If i got lets say 2304 from the camera (0x900) i saved it to the text file as 09 00 which i should get back to 2304 on the client machine and turn it in to a bitmap. I have no way of using json etc as they take so much space.

Comment: @Karter: that's all well and good and makes sense so far, but I fail to see why you'd want to go to any kind of "string" here. Everything you describe is pure binary data.  I think in JavaScript you'd handle it with something like an [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) (but I'm not a JavaScript developer, so maybe that's totally wrong). Anyway: avoid string and other "text-based" types for stuff like this, it'll just lead to pain and no gain. Also: calling 36TB "little space" makes me feel really, really old.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I will check the array buffer. The 36TB space will be barely enough for a camera that is 382x288 with 2 bytes per pixel that works 7/24 for 365 days at 5 fps (if i calculated right it will be around 34TB or so, if i did not you will see my asking about decompression on the server here :) ). Yes, i started with 8kb computers back in the 80's. Now we are talking terabytes.